# How to make an image's width resize itself with a defined height

Tags: css

I am trying to make an image resizable.
I have a specific height for this image: `height: 100%` (inside a container) and a `width: auto;` (i want the width to be adapted to the height about the natural image size).

Everything works fine when i access the page, but when i resize the window, the height is correctly resized, but the width keeps its initial value, i want it to be proportional (like when i access the page for the first time) to the height.

Is there a way to do it in CSS ? If not, what is the more optimize solution ?

Here is an illustration in code:

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
  <img alt="test" src="/img/test.png">
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.container {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
}

.container img {
  height: 100%;
  width: auto; //i need it to be adapted to each height about the natural image's dimensions
}
```

**UPDATE**

Here is a jsfiddle
[http://jsfiddle.net/CRGj6/1/](http://jsfiddle.net/CRGj6/2/)
Sometime it works sometime it doesn't...

Comment: Can you create a jsfiddle? your problem cannot be reproduced using given details.

Comment: `when i resize the window, the height is correctly resized, but the width keeps its initial value` how does the height change with window resize? Height is set to `100px` so it'll always remain `100px` regardless of window size.

Comment: Does it work in other browsers? I think this is an ie thing. In that case, try removing width:auto

Comment: That's right the issue seems to come from something else, i am working on a jsfiddle, i update the post as soon as possible. Thanks !

Comment: I made exactly the same code and it works on my jsfiddle... Is that possible that with a bigger DOM it could not be able to manage it ?
http://jsfiddle.net/CRGj6/
On the exact same case, the width's image stay fix when i resize the window...

Comment: No, there could be two CSS lines that are effecting the image size or a script that is altering it. If it is a script then that CSS would go inline for that element and would over ride your CSS. What is showing up in the debugger window?

Answer (score 0):

window resize affects only the width of the element but not the height. It is kinda make sense because if you resize the height, more content is scrollable that means don't do anything to width but to increase the scrollbar length (so more content to be scrolled). Assuming that you want to preserve the aspect ratio of the image,

```
.wrapper .container img {
  position: relative;
  height: auto;
  width: 100%;
}
```

would be the solution to this problem.

Comment: But i don't want the image take 100% of the width, i want the height take 100% of the height, and the width fit the minimum it has to keep to natural aspect ratio.

Comment: are you resizing the height of the window, then?

Comment: Yes when i resize the height of the window, the width of the image doesn't change.